Looking for a Modern Alternative to PHP Link Directory (phpLD) for a DMOZ-like Web Directory
Back in the day, I used PHP Link Directory (phpLD) to manage a DMOZ-style web directory. However, it seems like phpLD is no longer supported or in sync with modern web developments.
I’m looking for a modern alternative that offers similar features but aligns with current SEO standards and has a more contemporary design and interface. Ideally, the solution should:

Allow for user submissions and categorization of websites
Be easy to customize with modern themes
Integrate well with current SEO practices (e.g., schema markup, mobile-friendly, etc.)
Be actively maintained or supported
Preferably open-source or reasonably priced

Any recommendations?
